# How can I create an icon on my Macintosh desktop that takes me to a web page?

Tags: mac, icons, shortcuts, bookmarks, desktop-icons

How can I create an icon on my Macintosh desktop that takes me to a web page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To have a shortcut to a site in your dock is also possible

http://support.apple.com/kb/HT2450?viewlocale=en_US

Answer (score 1):

Highlight the URL in your browser and drag to your desktop.

Comment: This didn't work, but led me to a solution (posted as an alternate answer).  The URL itself is not drag-able for me, but the icon to its left is.

Answer (score 1):

Building on Daniel Standage's answer:

Go to the desired URL in firefox, find the small icon to the left of the URL and drag it to your desktop.